# dotPlot not properly displaying dot colors

Tags: r

I have a dot plot and I'd like to color the dots so I have a `d$color` vector that corresponds to the color for a particular dot.

Question 1:
When you run the code below you can see the dots are not colored properly?  Do you know how to color them properly?  The code needs to dynamically handle the situation where the colors change. For example in this case "red" is the first color but that will not always be the case.

Question 2:  Do you also know how to make the dots filled instead of transparent?

```
library(mosaic)
binwidth <- 1
dat <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
d <- data.frame(x=dat, color=c("red", "green", "blue", "blue", "purple", "red",
                               "red", "blue", "green", "green"))
dotPlot(~x, data=d, groups=color, 
        breaks=seq(min(d$x) - binwidth, max(d$x) + binwidth, binwidth), 
        cex=1, col=as.factor(d$color))
```

Question 3:  Can you run this code? The soltuion does not seem to work here:

```
n=50
r =rnorm(n)
dat = sample(r ,n= 1,size = n, replace = TRUE)
d = data.frame( x = dat, color = c(rep("red",n/2), rep("green",n/2)))
dotPlot(d$x,  breaks = seq(min(d$x)-.1,max(d$x)+.1,.1)) # this works
dotPlot(d$x,  breaks = seq(min(d$x)-.1,max(d$x)+.1,.1), groups = color,col = levels(d$color) ) # this does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To colour the points as desired, pass a vector of colours that corresponds to the colours that you want for your groups (so here, a vector of 4 colours, not a vector of 10 colours).

```
dotPlot(~x, data=d, groups=color, col=levels(d$color),
        breaks=seq(min(d$x) - binwidth, max(d$x) + binwidth, binwidth))
```

[image]

To change the symbol, use `pch` (see `?pch` for a list of built-in plotting characters).

```
dotPlot(~x, data=d, groups=color, col=levels(d$color), pch=20,
        breaks=seq(min(d$x) - binwidth, max(d$x) + binwidth, binwidth))
```

[image]

Comment: How does "col" know that the 8th dot should be blue? I am just curious how it can correctly color them if you don't pass the entire d$color?

Comment: @user3022875 If you tell it to group the points with `group=color`, then `col` refers to the groups' colours. The 3rd, 4th and 8th points all belong to the group "blue", so they all get the colour for that group (blue).

Comment: Thank you. Can you you run the added code in Question 3. It seems to not return dots

Comment: @user3022875 `dotPlot` doesn't know about `color` unless you specify `data=d`. Try `dotPlot(~x, data=d, breaks = seq(min(d$x)-.1,max(d$x)+.1,.1), groups=d$color, col=levels(d$color), pch=20)`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Q2, simply changing the type of "point" by default with the argument "pch".

```
dotPlot(~x, data=d, groups = color, breaks = seq(min(d$x)-binwidth, max(d$x)+binwidth,binwidth), cex = 1, col = d$color, pch = 16)
```